# From a list create a dictionary with Keys equal to values

Tags: python, dictionary

my pourpose is to create a dictionary starting from a list, where the keys are equal to the values.
What I have done till now is:

```
dicts = {}
keys = range(len(x))
values = x
for i in keys:
    dicts[i] = values[i]
```

the output is:

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

what I want is:

```
{a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
```

I don't know how modify the keys. Thanks you all.

Comment: `dicts[values[i]] = values[i]`

Comment: You can't have `{a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}` because that would require the variables `a`, `b`, `c` to exist and they don't. Do you mean `{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}`? If that is what you want, do `{v:v for v in values}`.

Comment: What are the keys? Do you have variables named `a`, `b`, and `c` whose values you want as the keys, or do you want the strings `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` to be the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dicts[values[i]] = values[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dict` function on zipping the list twice:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict(zip(*[x]*2))
```

---

```
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dict(zip(values, values))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your last line
Your saying : `dicts[i] = values[i]`
instead put : `dicts[values[i]] = values[i]`
Cause `i` is the index not the item in the list

and don't forget to define x first : `x = ['a','b','c']`

this will output :

{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension

```
values = ['a','b','c']
d = {v:v for v in values}
```